# EF 6.2 does not return result when querying database

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have this `DbContext`:

```
public class SomeDbContext : DbContext
{
   public SomeDbContext () : base("SomeConnectionString")
   {}

   public DbSet<Car> Cars { get; set; }

   protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
   {
      base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
   }
}
```

But when I want to query the database for `Cars`, nothing is returned.

Example:

```
var context = new SomeDbContext();
var cars = context.Cars.ToList(); // Nothing gets returned here...
```

However if I paste the SQL query to SSMS it returns the items just fine.

SQL query taken from Visual Studio debugger:

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent1].[Engine] AS [Engine],
    [Extent1].[StartTime] AS [StartTime], 
FROM 
    [dbo].[Cars] AS [Extent1]
```

I have verified that the connection string exists in the project.

Comment: " paste the SQL query to SSMS" - what SQL query?

Comment: I've updated the description :)

Comment: "I have verified that the Connection string exists in the project." -- Have you also verified that it points to the same server and database that you're connecting to in SSMS?

Comment: can you please wrap it in a try catch and see if any exception is caught? by the way do you have records in that table too?

Comment: @hvd Yes, it's a local SQL server I have running on my workstation

Comment: "does not return" and "returns nothing" is not the same, what actually happens? This seems to be a connection string problem

Comment: @Haris Just did what you suggested and no exceptions are caught. The table contains approx 200 records

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto nothing is returned when doing the var cars = context.Cars.ToList();

I agree it seems to be a connection string issue. Do you have any suggestions on how to test this?

Comment: Well, for starters, you could post the connection string and a screenshot of the SSMS window to show they are the same server, instance and database. Also, "nothing is returned" means "cars is assigned an empty collection"?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Just made it working by instantiating the DbContext base with the connection string directly from the app.config file instead of using the name of the ConnectionString

Comment: @Sasquatch You can make your program print the actual connection string in use (`context.Database.Connection.ConnectionString`, I think) to rule out the possibility of having accidentally put different connection strings in different config files, and looking at the wrong config file. If you then indeed get a different connection string from what you were expecting, search across all files in your solution to see where it's coming from.

Comment: @hvd Thx, just did this and found a problem:
ConnectionString on DbContext:
Data Source=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Initial Catalog=Cars;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True

The ConnectionString in my app.config:
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="SomeConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=Data_Cars;Integrated Security=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>

The InitialCatalog is simply missing the "Data_" part... Any idea why?

Comment: "Localhost" and "(localdb)\mssqllocaldb" are also different. Is your EF model in a separate project from your main app.config? I suspect the app.config inside the EF project is correct, but your main config, i.e. in the windows or web app, is wrong.

Comment: @Rhumborl True. Yes the model is in it's own project however the connection strings are identical in both projects.